# Concatenating file using cat command

Tags: linux, unix

I'm new to unix, and i was playing with commands while using cat command, i found unexpected output.

I had.

```
test and the content of test is
line 1
test2 and the content of test2 is
line 2
```

This is what i typed.

```
cat test2>>test>test3
```

The result is

```
line 2
```

so my question is why it's not

```
line 1
line 2
```

shouldn't this code concatenate test with test2 and them add it into test3?

Comment: If you do more research on how the **cat** syntax works, I don't see you asking this question. If you want to concatenate, you need to separate *text* & *test2* with a single space. Then pipe the output to *test3* using **>**. So what you have just done is take test2 and replace test and then replace test3

Comment: i didn't ask how to append using cat. i gave a cat syntax which doesn't result in errors, and i asked why i got this result.

Comment: You are getting it all wrong. OK you will solve this puzzle yourself. Do this first and tell me the result **cat test2>>test**

Comment: what i don't get it why u don't understand that i know that the syntax you provided works fine but this isn't what am asking for.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question: When you run the command **cat test2>>test>test3**, you expect the output to be line 1 <br>
line 2 that's separate lines. Is that correct?

Comment: well yes that's the answer i expected before Joni explains it. ty for ur effort btw(all i mean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect the standard output stream of a program multiple times like in

```
cat test2 >>test >test3
```

the redirections are set up in the order you write. In this case, the shell opens `test` in append mode and sets it as the the standard output for `cat`. Then it opens `test3` in overwrite mode and sets it as the standard output, overriding the previous redirection.

If `test` can be opened, the net effect of the entire command is the same as:

```
cat test2 >test3
```

That is, `line 2` is written  to `test3`. If you want to concatenate test and test2 to test3 you should use:

```
cat test test2 >test3
```

or do it in two steps:

```
cat test2 >>test
cat test >test3
```

Comment: now i'm starting to get it. so it take the first input as output then override it's mode and ignore other files in the middle, right?
 so when i swapped > & >> 
test2>test>>test3 why did it erased the content in test and it didnt append in test3, because the result in test3 is line2

Comment: with `cat test2>test>>test3`, the shell opens first  `test` in overwrite mode, which means the file is first truncated (emptied). Then it open test3 in append mode, so `cat` writes the contents of `test2` into `test3` after the existing contents. If you only find "line2" in test3 make sure that `test3` had something to begin with and that `test2` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
cat test1.txt test2.txt > test3.txt
```

Also check [What is Linux cat Command?](http://hscripts.com/tutorials/linux-commands/cat.html)

If you want to check how Cat command works then you may check this [tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1322).

> Using >> ensures any prior content of bigcats is preserved. The
>   content of panther is appended to bigcats. If you were to use the >
>   operator here, you would replace the contents of bigcats with the
>   contents of panther. Always use >> when you wish to add to the end of
>   an existing file.

Comment: i know i but i don't want to do that i want to understand how it works and why it didn't show up that result because when i tried to cat test2>test>>test3 it erased test

Comment: @user2954718:- Updated my answer. Hope that answers your query!

Comment: @user2954718 why not simply check the cat syntax

Comment: @user2954718 :- Also check the wiki for cat:- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)

Comment: @chelsea this has nothing to do with simple cat commands. i'm using 2 commands at the same time not one and i didn't get an error i got 2 weird outputs i'm trying to figure out why. this is merely academic.
as for Rahul if you check the code in my first comment here you see test is in the middle so the content of test should be the same as test2 then it's appended in test3 so why test's content got wiped out

Comment: You are mixing your comments here. Did you see my comment above? Every answer here all points to the way you used the syntax. All you are doing is taking output of one file and replacing other file if it exists or create new file if it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this and apply to yours:

```
file1
Hello

file2
Goodbye

cat file1 file2 > fileresult

fileresult
Hello
Goodbye
```